# Ruby on Rails: How to get nested_form_for new child ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-form-for

I have QuestionSet, Question, and Choice tables

```
class QuestionSet < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name
    has_many :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :correct_answer

    belongs_to :question_set
    has_many :choices
end

class Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :question_id, :value
    belongs_to :question
end
```

I want to assign the id of Choice as the correct_answer for Question. But since new nested_form_for child objects don't have real IDs yet, I can only assign the correct_answer for choices that have been saved already, but doesn't work for choices that have just been created through link_to_add. The simplified 'view' code below:

```
<!-- BTW 'f' below is QuestionSet -->
<%= f.fields_for :questions do |f_f| %>
    <!-- Question Name -->
    <%= f_f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f_f.fields_for :choices do |f_f_f| %>
        <!-- Designate as Correct Answer -->
        <%= f_f.radio_button :correct_answer, f_f_f.object.id %><!-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM-->
        <!-- Choice Name -->
        <%= f_f_f.text_field :value %> 

        <%= f_f_f.link_to_remove "Remove Choice" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f_f.link_to_add "Add Choice", :choices %>

    <%= f_f.link_to_remove "Remove Question" %>
<% end %>

<%= f.link_to_add "Add Question", :questions %>
```

Again the code only works and assigns the id of the choice-child as the 'correct_answer' of the Question only if the choice was saved before already and therefore it has an id already. But, it doesn't work for those newly created choice-children created by the link_to_add.

Any help would be gladly appreciated. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

why not move :correct_answer field to the Choices and make it boolean? This will simplify things a lot

Comment: Thank you! That will do. I never thought of it that way :) haha Thanks!

Comment: One thing though is that I now have a problem with the chocies. It used to be radio_button :correct_answer but now it's a checkbox for each choice, but I wanted it so that only one choice could be selected at a time. But I cannot make it a radiobutton anymore since correct_answer is now a Boolean and part of Choice :)

Comment: You can generate radio buttons per each choice, just make sure they have the same name:   <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk"> Milk  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Butter" checked> Butter  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Cheese"> Cheese'

Comment: I can't seem to make it work though because I am using RESTful in forms, the button 'name's are automatically created. Such is what follows:
ex. for choice 1:
<input id="test_question_set_questions_attributes_0_choices_attributes_0_is_correct_true" name="test_question_set[questions_attributes][0][choices_attributes][0][is_correct]" type="radio" value="true">

and for choice 2:
<input checked="checked" id="test_question_set_questions_attributes_0_choices_attributes_1_is_correct_true" name="test_question_set[questions_attributes][0][choices_attributes][1][is_correct]" type="radio" value="true">

Comment: I tried making them same names, but it doesn't save properly anymore. I guess because I used RESTful approach. Have I missed something bro? :)

Comment: sorry I need to sleep, will try to help you tomorrow :)